# Jenkins build breaks on SaxParsing xsd scheme

Tags: jenkins, jaxb, xsd, saxparseexception

i have a maven2 project which is built periodically by jenkins. The bad thing about it ... it won´t build anymore.
I´m not sure what has changed, because i don´t have any tickets in the code itself or jenkins configuration, but strange as it is..... the local build works.

Normally that would hint on a configuration problem in jenkins, but the error in jenkins is:

[ERROR] XJC while parsing schema(s) file:/global/contint/build_server/jenkins/jobs/ERIC_E4N%20Continuous-Trunk-Check/workspace/Eric4N-publishing-xsd/src/main/resources/E4N_E4D_InterfaceSalesAllowanceDoType.xsd[76,14]: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: 'SalesAllowanceDoType' is already defined

Locally I don´t get this error....

Any clues where I could continue my search ?

Thanks alot and Greetings !